# Generate models within Rails / db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Normally i generate modles with the command line like this:

```
rails g model Person name:string age:integer
```

Now i have one folder with about 20 Files that all have the same structur they look for eg like this:

```
rails g model Comment name:integer post:integer old:boolean .....
```

I would like to automate the process of the models generation, and because of this i ask how i should execute this files? Whitin a runner script? And how should i automatically run the `rake db:migrate`? Thanks

```
Dir.foreach('model_files') do |item|
  next if item == '.' or item == '..' 
  run item 
???
```

Comment: Why do you want automate user generation even further? What is you goal here?

Comment: In this folder are about 20 Files with this commands. If i would like to run all this migration with one command! I mean i dont want to paste each of this command to my command line! Hope you understand what i mean?

Comment: Those are not migrations! Those are rails built in scripts to generate bunch of the files, including migrations, model classes, tests, factories etc. Those commands are to be run once and only once, rerunning them won't do anything.

Comment: Yes i know! I never run this commands! Again, i have 20 files and each describes a model the content is for eg: `rails g model Person name:string ...`. If i wanted to generate this model also in my application i had to copy the conents and execute them seperatly in my command line! But is there some ruby code so that i can automatically put the contents to my console and let rails generate this models?

Answer (score 0):

I see no benefit in automating and improving this job. Running generators is only one step that takes seconds whereas the following steps (writing specs, validations, associations) will takes much longer.

But anyway, you can run a all of scripts in a folder with a simple shell command:

```
$ run-parts folder/to/scripts/*
```